# How do I grab an object in 3D acrobat using JavaScript and move it around

Tags: javascript, 3d, acrobat

How do I grab an object in 3D acrobat using JavaScript and move it around? I am able to use Keyboard Event Handler and move objects around.

Comment: That a HUGE question. Moving the selected mesh along a given axis based on mouse movements will be pretty simple but anything more than that is going to take a whole lot of math. Additionally, be aware that there's no collision detection so you may move an object inside another and "lose" it.

Comment: Thanks. If I can just move along an axis it will be big help. I do not need it to detect collision. The objects can end up touching. This is a link to what I want: http://www.microtype.com/showcase/3DAsst/TakeApart.pdf

Comment: Oh... I know that file. The script is a modified version of a sample that Adobe published while I was there. Are you trying to code this yourself or do you just want the script. You could contact Shlomo at MicroType to get the script.

Comment: I am trying to code myself but it would really speed things up if I could obtain this script. I have emailed Shlomo but received no response.

Comment: The original script on which this one was based was intended to be freely shared but no CC license information was added to the script so I can't just give it to you. However, the key is to use the Matrix4x4 object and translateInPlace the selected mesh based on the distance the mouse was moved. This is not going to be a trivial project.